# Tooltip is broken when encountering apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql, html, tags

I want to display `link`s of images , and their `title` attribute are from a MySQL database :

```
for ($i=0; $i<$ret['cnt']; $i++)
{
    $html .= "<td width='15'><a href='" . HTTP_MAIN . $ret[$i]['menu_url'] . "?action=".$ret[$i]['menu_action']."'><img src='" . HTTP_ICONES . $ret[$i]["menu_icone_img"] . "' title='".$ret[$i]["menu_icone_title"] . "' width='12' height='12'></a></td>";
}
```

As you can see the title attribute is from $ret[$i]["menu_icone_title"]. Here is the query :

```
$sSQL = "SELECT menu_icone_img, menu_icone_title, menu_url, menu_action
                FROM menu 
                WHERE menu_icone_flag = 1
                ORDER BY menu_icone_ordre";

        $this->db->query($sSQL) ;
        $ret['cnt'] = $this->db->num_rows();
        $i = 0;
        while ( $this->db->next_record() ) {
            $ret[$i]["menu_icone_img"]  = stripslashes($this->db->f('menu_icone_img'));
            $ret[$i]["menu_icone_title"] = stripslashes($this->db->f('menu_icone_title'));
            $ret[$i]["menu_url"]    = stripslashes($this->db->f('menu_url'));
            $ret[$i]["menu_action"] = stripslashes($this->db->f('menu_action'));
            $i++;
        }
```

The problem is when the "menu_icone_title" column has apostrophe inside , like `Initialisation des niveaux d'activités`

So in runtime the tooltip is broken : `Initialisation des niveaux d` .

So how to show all of the text ?

Comment: htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($var))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace :

```
$ret[$i]["menu_icone_title"]
```

By

```
str_replace("'","\\'",$ret[$i]["menu_icone_title"]);
```

Comment: No ! the tooltip is still broken !

Comment: I added another backslash, try it out, if it does not work you can use double quotes for you title (like this : title="Initialisation des niveaux d'activités" ) instead of single quote (like this : title='Initialisation des niveaux d'activités')

Comment: ok , I replaced the single-quote of the PHP string to simple-quote and vice-versa for the attributes ! And it works !

Answer (score 0):

HTML should really be outside of any PHP. E.g.

```
<?php 
function cleantext ($string) {
  return htmlentities($string);
}

for ($i=0; $i<$ret['cnt']; $i++)
{
    ?>
    <td width="15">
       <a href="<?php echo HTTP_MAIN . cleantext($ret[$i]['menu_url']); ?>?action=<?php echo $ret[$i]['menu_action'];?>">
         <img src="<?php echo HTTP_ICONES . cleantext($ret[$i]["menu_icone_img"]); ?>" title="<?php echo cleantext($ret[$i]["menu_icone_title"]); ?>" width="12" height="12" />
       </a>
    </td>
  <?php
}
?>
```

It makes your code a lot more readable / easier to maintain.

I've also added a function around any output, which will clean the output for you. At the moment all this function is doing is doing [htmlentites](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) on the string, but you could easily extend it if/when required.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I disagree that this is a more readable format.  A simple echo that is formatted by tabbing has much less extraneous characters cluttering up the code.